# Bash script find/sed not working

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following line in my bash script:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print |
xargs sed -i 's/http\:\/\/version2\.staging\.myname\.com//g'
```

and it's giving me the following error:

```
sed: 1: "./instant/index. ...": invalid command code .
```

What I'm trying to do is replace any occurrence of `http://version2.staging.myname.com` with `/`.  How do you do it?

Comment: xargs will try to fit as many as possible by default, so sed received "s/......../g file1 file2 file3 .... filen". It then tries to interpret everything except the last (filen) as a command that should oper on `filen`. You could just add "-n 1" to xargs invocation so it only outputs them one by one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OSX try this:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i.bak 's#http://version2\.staging\.myname\.com##g' '{}' \; -print
```

Comment: To get rid of the .bak file, would I just remove .bak from the command above ?

Comment: You can just use `-i''` instead of `-i.bak` but I believe `.bak` is nice feature in case something goes wrong in sed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use something like:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i 's|http://version2\.staging\.myname\.com/|/|g' '{}' ';'
```

To test this out, you can first insert an `echo` statement

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec echo sed -i 's|http://version2\.staging\.myname\.com/|/|g' '{}' ';'
```

... that will tell you if the output will be what you expect.  I always recommend doing a dry-run with `echo` first before any mass update.  Also you can use `|` as an alternate regex delimiter to avoid using as many `/' in the paths.

Comment: Here's the output of the echo statement: sed -i s|http://version2\.staging\.myname\.com/|/|g ./instant/index.html but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: hmm, so you can't execute that line on the command line?  Is this linux or some other version of unix?  I'd try running the command on just one file first to validate the sed syntax.

Comment: Ah, that's BSD.  I would need to check the syntax that sed is expecting.  You might try `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using a Mac (*and now I see a comment that you are on an iMac*).  On Mac OS X, the `sed -i` option requires an argument.  That makes sense of your error message. The `sed` command is interpreting your `s/...//g` command as the suffix to use for the back up file; it is then trying to interpret the first file name as the `sed` script, and fortunately, that is not working.

Additionally, you can avoid most of the escaping issues by using some character other than `/` as the delimiter for `s///`. Also, it is generally better (especially on Macs where file paths often end up with spaces in them) to avoid `xargs` and use `-exec` in `find`, along with the `+` option to do what `xargs` does — namely group many file names into one command invocation.

This leads to:

```
find . -name "*.html" -type f \
    -exec sed -i .bak -e 's%http://version2.staging.myname.com%%g' {} +
```

(NB: strictly, that will map `http://version2-staging*myname@com` to `/` too; if you're really worried about that, by all means escape the dots in the URL.)

If you want to get rid of the `.bak` files afterwards:

```
find . -name '*.bak' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```